# How to tag to parent of the parent in taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a parent term *Regional* and in *Regional* I have several languages say *English* etc. I have songs tagged with these languages.

If I select *Regional* I want to select all songs under all languages in the parent term *Regional*. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.